# Using ActionChooser with Attachment for email and Facebook-App in Android

Tags: android, facebook, email

I trying to create a "publish" button for an image in my android app, that works with the Facebook App and Email.

This is my code (imagePath is something like "/sdcard/myapp/image.jpg"

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+imagePath));

sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enjoy the photo");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

This works perfectly for sending the email with the attachment, but it doesn't work with the Facebook App. 
If I'm using

```
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imagePath));
```

the publishing for Facebook works - but the email-attachment isn't send anymore.

Any ideas what could do it for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested ... I solved it in an indirect way:

```
    File imageFile = new File(imagePath);
    String url = "";
    try {
         url = Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), imageFile.getName(), imageFile.getName());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
```

Answer (score 1):

mseo means, install the (free) facebook app on your phone!

I just adapted mseo's code to my own app and shared a picture via Gmail and Facebook. I see a list of providers which includes Facebook (I have the FB application installed on my phone, I would not see the FB option otherwise), and also Blogger, Wordpress, Twitter, Dropbox etc.

Edited: to send an existing file, better:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
```

Edited: this works well with email and Dropbox. It also works with Facebook (via the official Facebook Android app), but for some reason the original picture is deleted from the SD card after posting to Facebook. This has been reported by others and is probably due a bug in the Facebook app. I worked around it by backing up the image before sharing and restoring it from the backup later of needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to define a ContentProvider which converts your file:// Uri to a content:// Uri.

You can try this one : http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/FileManager/src/org/openintents/filemanager/FileManagerProvider.java

Comment: Thank you for this approach - this could work, too. But I solved it in an easier way for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my application i need to share some message via email, gmail, txt and facebook.
I am using this piece of code

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via"));

This code provides me a list of options which contains share via email, gmail and messaging.
How to add facebook in this list?

Comment: How to install the facebook app? I have included facebook for android sdk in my application. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook expect url to image.
This explains why code

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imagePath));
```

works fine. Using url facebook is getting imiage data and stores it to server.